# Hibernate lazy-load transient fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading, transient

I expect that this is an unusual use-case.

Say I have a entity class Foo:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String bar;

    @Transient
    private long bazz;

    ...
}
```

I also have an Interceptor defined such that Foo.bazz is initialized when instances of Foo are read from the database:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onLoad(
        Object entity,
        Serializable id,
        Object[] state,
        String[] propertyNames,
        Type[] types) {

        if(entity instanceof Foo) {
            Foo foo = (Foo)entity;

            long bazzValue = ... // some very heavyweight code

            foo.setBazz(bazzValue);
        }

        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

So far, so good. But not all code paths will need the value of every Foo instance's bazz field. This means that the heavyweight code to find a value for each and every instance of Foo is sometimes needlessly invoked.

How do I go about avoiding invoking the code to find a value for bazz unless Foo.getBazz() is actually invoked?

Comment: Is there any reason you cant run your heavyweight code in Foo.getBazz()? What is the heavyweight doing?

Comment: I guess you need to implement some type of proxy class. But really i do not understand why you are doing this? And what is heavyweight code, lot of db calls? if it is so, this is the wrong place to do this.

Comment: please provide your use case, may be we can assist you better.

Comment: The actual use case is this: class Foo represents a user. Fields on the user will be updated very rarely, and can be normal hibernate-mapped fields. However, the @Transient fields represent summary data about the users -- call it, for example, the number of orders processed for this user in the last 30 days. This number conceptually belongs to the user, but is ultimately backed by a very heavyweight query. We want a getter on the User model for this number, but we don't want to execute the query unless the code actually invokes the getter.

Comment: And we don't want to put the heavyweight code directly in the model because it would be a gross violation of the layering we have in place in this application. The models would have to know about services to directly invoke it!

Answer (score 0):

OK, upon reflection:

Use the interceptor to populate an object into the Foo instance. This object can do the lazy initialization without violating the separation of concerns.